# Why is this PHP code accessing a MySQL database not working?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

require('database.php');
$user = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("insert into Userinfo (username, password, location) values (?, ?, ?)");
    if(!$stmt) {
        //printf("Query prep failed: %s\n", mysqli->error);
        echo "query prep failed".$mysqli->error;
        exit;
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $password, $location);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    error_log("username ".$user, 3, "/tmp/php_error.log");
} 
?>
```

Database.php

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'php', 'passtheword', 'Android');

if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
printf("Connection Failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
exit;
}
?>
```

This query is not modifying my database for some reason.  I know 'database.php' is valid, and I don't get an error from the if(!$stmt) section.  Nothing breaks, it just doesn't modify the table, Userinfo.  Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: show us `database.php` and do you have `error_reporting` enabled?

Comment: It might be because you are binding $username but your $_POSTed variable in your code is $user

Comment: Also, what does your error log say?

Comment: Oh shoot, that's almost certainly it.  Thank you.   I haven't actually been able to figure out how to use error log yet.

Comment: During developement, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` if you're not already doing so.

Comment: Are you working on localhost (your computer) or using a web-hosting company? A web-hosting company should have error_log as one of the files in the directory that holds your index.php or index.html file. I develop locally using Wamp Server 2 and error log was included by default. The file will contain all notices, warnings, and errors in your php, tell you the line where the transgression resides, and the time it was detected.

Answer (score 2):

Change `$user` to `$username`. You are binding and inserting `$username` but you only `$_POST` to and define `$user`